# I need the *nix top command for Git Bash

Tags: git, git-bash

I have Git for Windows installed and I am using the `Msys` flavour of `Git Bash`:

```
$ uname -o
Msys
```

I do not want to install the `MinGW` suite and i cannot find the `top` command from the `Msys` [repo](https://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/).
The best would be an *exe* that i can download, extract or build and copy to

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin
```

Comment: `top` is part of procps-ng / procps. For the record Git for Windows isn't exactly msys. For one it lacks the package manager. On the other hand, its `git` is a mingw/native build AFAIK (while in msys for some reason you only get an msys build of `git`, while there's mingw/native build of e.g. python / emacs).